# How To automatically load in bash_profile

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

Hi I have various keys in my .bash_profile:

```
ex export blah=blahblah
```

however when I try to access them in python:

```
from os import getenv
aws_access_key_id=getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY');
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/database.py", line 25, in <module>
  conn= S3Connection(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key);
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 190, in __init__
  validate_certs=validate_certs, profile_name=profile_name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 572, in __init__
  host, config, self.provider, self._required_auth_capability())
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/boto/auth.py", line 883, in get_auth_handler
  'Check your credentials' % (len(names), str(names)))
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

Edit:
Os.environ seems to be the same as getenv...

However I'm not quite sure how to use it given that it takes in 2 params?

I think the solution is getting my my bash shell to be run in eclipse pydev. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If using `os.environ` works, i don't see the problem.

Comment: I tried os.environ and got (oh and environ has no callable environ():  File "/Users/tai/Documents/workspace/testSelenium/testS/database.py", line 21, in <module>
    aws_access_key_id=environ.__getitem__('AWS_ACCESS_KEY');
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY'

Comment: How is your Python process being run?  Is it being run from a non-login shell?  Bash only loads the `.bash_profile` file if it's running as a login shell, see the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files).

Comment: Oh, its being run from pydev... is there no way to access it without running from bash?